# Validar data no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Eu gero uma data, e preciso saber se ela é válida, caso não seja, preciso diminuir o dia dela, até ser válido.

```
set @data = (select convert(date,CONCAT(@dia,'-',month(@vencimento1),'-',year(@vencimento1))))
set @vencimento = (select DATEADD(month, 1, @data))
```

Tentei algo como:

```
if (select isdate(DATEADD(month, 1, @data))) = 1 
    set @vencimento = (select DATEADD(month, 1, @data))
else
    set @vencimento = (select dateadd(day, -1, @data), DATEADD(month, 1, @data))
```

Porém também não dá certo. Qual seria a melhor maneira de verificar ?

**EDIT**

Eu cheguei neste código com a junção das respostas:

```
while(isdate((CONCAT(@dia,'-',month(@vencimento1),'-',year(@vencimento1)))) = 0 ) 
        set @dia = @dia - 1;
        set @data = (select convert(date,CONCAT(@dia,'-',month(@vencimento1),'-',year(@vencimento1))))
        print @data
        set @vencimento = (select DATEADD(month, 1, @data))
```

Porém o que acontece, ele não gera o dia correto, era para gerar por exemplo no dia 31/12, ele gera pro dia 30/12, e em janeiro 31/01, e em fevereiro ele pega o dia 29.

Comment: Que DATA seria essa? Por que tem 2 datas vencimento e data? só pode ser dias uteis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poderia ser feito assim:

```
declare @dia varchar(2)
declare @mes varchar(2)
declare @ano  varchar(4)
declare @data date


set @dia = 40;
set @mes = 80;
set @ano = 2019

begin
   if ( @dia > 31 ) set @dia = 31
   if ( @mes > 12 ) set @mes = 12
   if ( @ano > 2019 ) set @ano = 2019


   while ( isdate( concat( @mes, '-', @dia, '-', @ano )) = 0 ) 
      set @dia = @dia - 1;

   set @data = cast( concat( @mes, '-', @dia, '-', @ano ) as date )
   print concat( @mes, '-', @dia, '-', @ano )

   print @data
end
```

Comment: Eu tentei algo como `while (select isdate(dateadd(DAY, @dia, (select DATEADD(month, 1, CAST(@vencimento1 AS datetime)))))) = 1 
   set @dia = @dia - 1;
   set @data = DATEADD(DAY, @dia, (select dateadd(month, 1, @vencimento1)))` mas ele não executa.

Comment: Não entendi porque você não consegue usar o código que postei.

Comment: Consigo, mas estou adaptando para o meu, pois eu preciso mudar na data, pois se for em dezembro, e ele adicionar somente no mes, eu preciso tratar o ano também, e a questão do dia.

Comment: Altere a pergunta e poste quais são as possibilidades.

Comment: Use esse código. Nos valores iniciais, coloque os valores que você estará recebendo e veja se não vai funcionar.

Comment: Deu certo, para validar a data, fiz assim `while(isdate((CONCAT(@dia,'-',month(@vencimento1),'-',year(@vencimento1)))) = 0 ) 
   set @dia = @dia - 1;
   set @data = (select convert(date,CONCAT(@dia,'-',month(@vencimento1),'-',year(@vencimento1))))
   print @data
   set @vencimento = (select DATEADD(month, 1, @data))` só qu eu gostaria que ele verificasse um mês para frente, e adicionasse conforme o ano e mês. Obrigado.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Da forma que está, caso a data não seja válida (considerando seu `if` de validação), você está setando dois valores para a variável `@vencimento` (`(select dateadd(day, -1, @data), DATEADD(month, 1, @data))`). Este é o erro apresentado!

Deixa apenas a primeira expressão que deve resolver o que você precisa:

```
if (select isdate(DATEADD(month, 1, @data))) = 1 
    select @vencimento = DATEADD(month, 1, @data)
else
    select @vencimento = DATEADD(day, -1, @data)
```

Dá uma olhada [nesse teste](https://rextester.com/YTHJFY1881).

---

**editado**

Considerando `@data` sendo do tipo `date` (vide comentário desta resposta), é necessário um *cast* para ela ser usada pela função `dateadd` ([outro exemplo](https://rextester.com/QJYQZ62454)):

```
if (select isdate(DATEADD(month, 1, CAST(@data AS datetime)))) = 1 
    select @vencimento = DATEADD(month, 1, CAST(@data AS datetime))
else
    select @vencimento = DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(@data AS datetime))
```

Comment: Quando adiciono, ele me retorna este erro `Tipo de dados de argumento date inválido para o argumento 1 da função isdate.`

Comment: `@data` é do tipo _datetime_? Se não, precisará converter antes de usar a função `dateadd`

Comment: @data é `@data date,`

Comment: @Mariana alterei a resposta considerando o tipo de `@data`

Comment: @Mariana, deu certo?

Comment: Eu estava fazendo os testes, por isso ainda não respondi, não deu, pois ele está pulando o mês, ele está indo de 2 em 2, estou adaptando entre as duas respostas, e a data ele tem que pegar o `@dia`, e não a data que está no `@data`

Comment: Estou tentando algo como `while (select isdate(dateadd(DAY, @dia, (select DATEADD(month, 1, CAST(@vencimento1 AS datetime)))))) = 1 
   set @dia = @dia - 1;
   set @data = DATEADD(DAY, @dia, (select dateadd(month, 1, @vencimento1)))` porém não executa.